# SQL query returning UNIQUE *pairs* of responses

Tags: mysql, select, unique

How do I write a SQL query that returns rows with unique *pairs* of specified fields.

For example, given the table

```
(1, 'Bill Smith', '1 Main Street'),
(2, 'Harriet Jones', '2 Cherry Street'),
(3, 'Bill Smith', '1 West 125th Street'),
(4, 'Susan Smith', '1 Main Street'),
(5, 'Bill Smith', '1 Main Street')
```

I want to SELECT with unique name/address pairs, and get back (for this example)

```
(1, 'Bill Smith', '1 Main Street'),
(2, 'Harriet Jones', '2 Cherry Street'),
(3, 'Bill Smith', '1 West 125th Street'),
(4, 'Susan Smith', '1 Main Street')
```

This example is also available at

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d4b4/1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a select distinct of the value you need

```
 select distinct name, address from your_table ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a  query with `DISTINCT`. You should select only the data columns for that purpose.

Edit: Oh, the second table was just the desired result - forget the UNION.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: Not nessessary since there's an answer with the complete query ;-)

Comment: Fair enough. I managed to convince myself that this task was more complicated than it really was.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` to create a group per name/address pair and get the minimum id per group. Then you can just pick the rows with those IDs;

```
SELECT id, name, address 
FROM testThing
WHERE id IN (
 SELECT MIN(id) FROM testThing GROUP BY name, address
);
```

If you don't want to select the id, it's simpler to just use `DISTINCT` on the other fields, as scaisEdge shows in his answer.

Comment: Thanks. I anticipate this technique being useful as my application gets more complex in the future.